# Getting the group values in the ReplaceAllStringFunc callback

Tags: regex, go

Im trying to replace a string with random numbers with the number range determined in the string

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "math/rand"
    "regexp"
    "strconv"
)

func replaceFunc(s string) string {
    groups := //?? How do i get the current mach groups
    return rand.Intn( groups[2] - groups[1]) + groups[1]
}

func main() {
    rand.Seed(time.Now().Unix())
    repl := "1,10 1,50 1,12 1,2 1,3"
    repl = regexp.MustCompile("(\\d+),(\\d+)").ReplaceAllStringFunc(repl, replaceFunc)
    fmt.Println(repl)
}
```

How would I get the regex groups when replacing?

Comment: your question not clear for me. What you want get as result?

Comment: I want every (\d+),(\d+) regex match to replaced with a unique random number that ranges between the first digit and the second digit.
So "1,2 3,4 5,6" would re replaced with (for example) "2 4 5", because the first number is between 1-2, then the next is 3-4 then the next is between 5-6.

Answer (score 1):

You will get each match individually as an argument to the function (`replaceFunc` will be called once per match, but not once per group).

You could use `strings.Split` to split up the numbers, and then convert them to ints:

https://play.golang.org/p/ks0tkMQ2TY

```
func replaceFunc(s string) string {
    pieces:= strings.Split(s, ",")
    a,_ := strconv.Atoi(pieces[0])
    b,_ := strconv.Atoi(pieces[1])
    return strconv.Itoa(rand.Intn( b - a) + a)
}

func main() {
    rand.Seed(time.Now().Unix())
    repl := "1,10 1,50 1,12 1,2 1,3"
    repl = regexp.MustCompile("(\\d+),(\\d+)").ReplaceAllStringFunc(repl, replaceFunc)
    fmt.Println(repl)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

this functionality is missing from official package. there was a effort to add it but apparently it was rejected by the authors:

https://codereview.appspot.com/106360043

there's a third party project which has implemented a similiar functionality:

https://github.com/agext/regexp

it can also be implemented using `FindAllSubmatchIndex`:

(from https://gist.github.com/elliotchance/d419395aa776d632d897)

```
package main

import (
    "math/rand"
    "regexp"
    "strconv"
)

func ReplaceAllStringSubmatchFunc(re *regexp.Regexp, str string, repl func([]string) string) string {
    result := ""
    lastIndex := 0

    for _, v := range re.FindAllSubmatchIndex([]byte(str), -1) {
        var groups []string
        for i := 0; i < len(v); i += 2 {
            if v[i] == -1 || v[i+1] == -1 {
                groups = append(groups, "")
            } else {
                groups = append(groups, str[v[i]:v[i+1]])
            }
        }

        result += str[lastIndex:v[0]] + repl(groups)
        lastIndex = v[1]
    }

    return result + str[lastIndex:]
}

func main() {
    original := "1,10 1,50 1,12 1,2 1,3"
    exp := regexp.MustCompile("(\\d+),(\\d+)")
    replaced := ReplaceAllStringSubmatchFunc(exp, original, func(groups []string) string {
        v1, _ := strconv.Atoi(groups[1])
        v2, _ := strconv.Atoi(groups[2])
        return strconv.Itoa(rand.Intn(v2-v1) + v1)
    })
    println(replaced)
}
```

here is a similar code for `[]byte` matching:

https://gist.github.com/slimsag/14c66b88633bd52b7fa710349e4c6749